# Image post into facebook wall from android sdcard

Tags: android, facebook

I just wanna post images from my android sdcard into facebook wall.I used below code.But couldn't able to see image post on FB wall.

My code:

```
private void fbWallPost() {
                facebook = new Facebook("My appId");
                asyncRunner = new AsyncFacebookRunner(facebook);
                facebook.authorize(facebook.this, new String[] { "user_status",
                        "user_about_me", "email", "read_stream",
                        "publish_stream" }, new DialogListener() {

                public void onComplete(Bundle values) {

                    JSONObject jObject;
                    try {
                        jObject = new JSONObject(facebook.request("me"));
                        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(
                                "/sdcard/codeofaninja.jpg");
                        Bitmap bi = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(fis);
                        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                        bi.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                        data = baos.toByteArray();

                        Bundle params = new Bundle();
                        params.putString("method", "photos.upload");
                        params.putByteArray("picture", data);

                        asyncRunner.request("me/photos", params, "POST",
                                new mRequestListener(), null);

                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (JSONException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    } catch (IOException e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                public void onFacebookError(FacebookError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(facebook.this,
                            "Facebook onFacebookError", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                            .show();
                }

                public void onError(DialogError e) {
                    Toast.makeText(facebook.this, "Facebook onError",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                public void onCancel() {

                }
            });
        }

    });
```

Comment: s.Im using facebook SDK for android

Comment: A link is given bellow. download this code (fb sdk) then in this have 2 class 1 for connect to face book  and other for post to facebook.
and also use the code in class class "public void postToFacebook" .

Comment: In this link example.,ur posting images from URL.But i want to post image from sdcard (like mnt/sdcard/cartoon.jpg)

Comment: Hello brother, 
  You must put some effort in it. "_selectedImagePath" is the path of image from gallery..

You must write a function for select image from gallery and take the path as "_selectedImagePath".

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code for share image form sdcard

```
public void shareimage(View v) {


         Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
         share.setType("image/jpeg");

         share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,Uri.parse(
         "file:///mnt/sdcard/test/v1327056571768.3gpp"));

         startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));

}
```

And also follow following [link](http://dilipdevelopment.blogspot.in/2012/04/display-image-from-specific-folder-with.html),I have posted on my Blog.

Comment: Nope.I dont want to share my images,i just wanna post images into facebook wall.Pls check what mistake ive done on this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi please check the following code may its helps you:-

```
package com.example.facebookuploadandroid;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.Callback;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.facebook.AppEventsLogger;
import com.facebook.FacebookAuthorizationException;
import com.facebook.FacebookException;
import com.facebook.FacebookOperationCanceledException;
import com.facebook.FacebookRequestError;
import com.facebook.HttpMethod;
import com.facebook.Request;
import com.facebook.Response;
import com.facebook.Session;
import com.facebook.SessionState;
import com.facebook.UiLifecycleHelper;
import com.facebook.model.GraphObject;
import com.facebook.model.GraphPlace;
import com.facebook.model.GraphUser;
import com.facebook.widget.FacebookDialog;
import com.facebook.widget.FriendPickerFragment;
import com.facebook.widget.LoginButton;
import com.facebook.widget.PickerFragment;
import com.facebook.widget.PlacePickerFragment;
import com.facebook.widget.ProfilePictureView;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity
{

    private static final String PERMISSION = "publish_actions";
    private static final Location SEATTLE_LOCATION = new Location("") {
        {
            setLatitude(47.6097);
            setLongitude(-122.3331);
        }
    };

    private final String PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY = "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook:PendingAction";

    private Button postStatusUpdateButton;
    private Button postPhotoButton;
    private Button pickFriendsButton;
    private Button pickPlaceButton;
    private LoginButton loginButton;
    private ProfilePictureView profilePictureView;
    private TextView greeting;
    private PendingAction pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
    private ViewGroup controlsContainer;
    private GraphUser user;
    private GraphPlace place;
    private List<GraphUser> tags;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialog;
    private boolean canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos;

    private enum PendingAction {
        NONE, POST_PHOTO, POST_STATUS_UPDATE
    }

    private UiLifecycleHelper uiHelper;

    private Session.StatusCallback callback = new Session.StatusCallback() {
        @Override
        public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
            onSessionStateChange(session, state, exception);
        }
    };

    private FacebookDialog.Callback dialogCallback = new FacebookDialog.Callback() {
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Exception error, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", String.format("Error: %s", error.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onComplete(FacebookDialog.PendingCall pendingCall, Bundle data) {
            Log.d("HelloFacebook", "Success!");
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        uiHelper = new UiLifecycleHelper(this, callback);
        uiHelper.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (savedInstanceState != null) {
            String name = savedInstanceState.getString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY);
            pendingAction = PendingAction.valueOf(name);
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        loginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.login_button);
        loginButton.setUserInfoChangedCallback(new LoginButton.UserInfoChangedCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onUserInfoFetched(GraphUser user) {
                MainActivity.this.user = user;
                updateUI();
                // It's possible that we were waiting for this.user to be
                // populated in order to post a
                // status update.
                handlePendingAction();
            }
        });

        profilePictureView = (ProfilePictureView) findViewById(R.id.profilePicture);
        greeting = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.greeting);

        postStatusUpdateButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postStatusUpdateButton);
        postStatusUpdateButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostStatusUpdate();
            }
        });

        postPhotoButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.postPhotoButton);
        postPhotoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPostPhoto();
            }
        });

        pickFriendsButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickFriendsButton);
        pickFriendsButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPickFriends();
            }
        });

        pickPlaceButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pickPlaceButton);
        pickPlaceButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                onClickPickPlace();
            }
        });

        controlsContainer = (ViewGroup) findViewById(R.id.main_ui_container);

        final FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        Fragment fragment = fm.findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_container);
        if (fragment != null) {
            // If we're being re-created and have a fragment, we need to a) hide
            // the main UI controls and
            // b) hook up its listeners again.
            controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (fragment instanceof FriendPickerFragment) {
                setFriendPickerListeners((FriendPickerFragment) fragment);
            } else if (fragment instanceof PlacePickerFragment) {
                setPlacePickerListeners((PlacePickerFragment) fragment);
            }
        }

        // Listen for changes in the back stack so we know if a fragment got
        // popped off because the user
        // clicked the back button.
        fm.addOnBackStackChangedListener(new FragmentManager.OnBackStackChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onBackStackChanged() {
                if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount() == 0) {
                    // We need to re-show our UI.
                    controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

        // Can we present the share dialog for regular links?
        canPresentShareDialog = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.SHARE_DIALOG);
        // Can we present the share dialog for photos?
        canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos = FacebookDialog.canPresentShareDialog(this, FacebookDialog.ShareDialogFeature.PHOTOS);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        uiHelper.onResume();

        // Call the 'activateApp' method to log an app event for use in
        // analytics and advertising reporting. Do so in
        // the onResume methods of the primary Activities that an app may be
        // launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.activateApp(this);

        updateUI();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        uiHelper.onSaveInstanceState(outState);

        outState.putString(PENDING_ACTION_BUNDLE_KEY, pendingAction.name());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        uiHelper.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data, dialogCallback);
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        uiHelper.onPause();

        // Call the 'deactivateApp' method to log an app event for use in
        // analytics and advertising
        // reporting. Do so in the onPause methods of the primary Activities
        // that an app may be launched into.
        AppEventsLogger.deactivateApp(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        uiHelper.onDestroy();
    }

    private void onSessionStateChange(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) {
        if (pendingAction != PendingAction.NONE
                && (exception instanceof FacebookOperationCanceledException || exception instanceof FacebookAuthorizationException)) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).setTitle("Cancle").setMessage("Not Granted").setPositiveButton("Ok", null).show();
            pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;
        } else if (state == SessionState.OPENED_TOKEN_UPDATED) {
            handlePendingAction();
        }
        updateUI();
    }

    private void updateUI() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        boolean enableButtons = (session != null && session.isOpened());

        postStatusUpdateButton.setEnabled(enableButtons || canPresentShareDialog);
        postPhotoButton.setEnabled(enableButtons || canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);
        pickFriendsButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);
        pickPlaceButton.setEnabled(enableButtons);

        if (enableButtons && user != null) {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(user.getId());
            greeting.setText(user.getFirstName());
        } else {
            profilePictureView.setProfileId(null);
            greeting.setText(null);
        }
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("incomplete-switch")
    private void handlePendingAction() {
        PendingAction previouslyPendingAction = pendingAction;
        // These actions may re-set pendingAction if they are still pending, but
        // we assume they
        // will succeed.
        pendingAction = PendingAction.NONE;

        switch (previouslyPendingAction) {
        case POST_PHOTO:
            postPhoto();
            break;
        case POST_STATUS_UPDATE:
            postStatusUpdate();
            break;
        }
    }

    private interface GraphObjectWithId extends GraphObject
    {
        String getId();
    }

    private void showPublishResult(String message, GraphObject result, FacebookRequestError error) {
        String title = null;
        String alertMessage = null;
        if (error == null) {
            title = "success";
            String id = result.cast(GraphObjectWithId.class).getId();
            alertMessage = "successfully_posted_post";
        } else {
            title = "error";
            alertMessage = error.getErrorMessage();
        }

        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(title).setMessage(alertMessage).setPositiveButton("Ok", null).show();
    }

    private void onClickPostStatusUpdate() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE, canPresentShareDialog);
    }

    private FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForLink() {
        return new FacebookDialog.ShareDialogBuilder(this).setName("Hello Facebook")
                .setDescription("The 'Hello Facebook' sample application showcases simple Facebook integration")
                .setLink("http://developers.facebook.com/android");
    }

    private void postStatusUpdate() {
        if (canPresentShareDialog) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForLink().build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (user != null && hasPublishPermission()) {
            final String message = user.getFirstName();
            Request request = Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), message, place, tags, new Request.Callback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                    showPublishResult(message, response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                }
            });
            request.executeAsync();
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_STATUS_UPDATE;
        }
    }

    private void onClickPostPhoto() {
        performPublish(PendingAction.POST_PHOTO, canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos);
    }

    private FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(Bitmap... photos) {
        return new FacebookDialog.PhotoShareDialogBuilder(this).addPhotos(Arrays.asList(photos));
    }

    private void postPhoto() {
        Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(this.getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        if (canPresentShareDialogWithPhotos) {
            FacebookDialog shareDialog = createShareDialogBuilderForPhoto(image).build();
            uiHelper.trackPendingDialogCall(shareDialog.present());
        } else if (hasPublishPermission()) {

            // Request request =
            // Request.newUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image,
            // "", "", new Request.Callback() {
            // @Override
            // public void onCompleted(Response response) {
            // showPublishResult("photo_post", response.getGraphObject(),
            // response.getError());
            // }
            // });
            // request.executeAsync();
            Request request = newMyUploadPhotoRequest(Session.getActiveSession(), image, "Teste Caption", "teste description",
                    new Request.Callback() {
                        @Override
                        public void onCompleted(Response response) {
                            showPublishResult("POSTED", response.getGraphObject(), response.getError());
                        }
                    });
            Request.executeBatchAsync(request);
        } else {
            pendingAction = PendingAction.POST_PHOTO;
        }
    }

    public static Request newMyUploadPhotoRequest(Session session, Bitmap image, String caption, String description,
            com.facebook.Request.Callback callback2) {
        Bundle parameters = new Bundle(3);
        parameters.putParcelable("picture", image);
        parameters.putString("caption", caption);
        parameters.putString("description", description);

        return new Request(session, "me/photos", parameters, HttpMethod.POST, callback2);

    }

    // public static Request newMyUploadPhotoRequest(Session session, Bitmap
    // image, String caption,String description,
    // Callback callback) {
    // Bundle parameters = new Bundle(3);
    // parameters.putParcelable(PICTURE_PARAM, image);
    // parameters.putString("caption",caption);
    // parameters.putString("description",description );
    //
    // return new Request(session, MY_PHOTOS, parameters, HttpMethod.POST,
    // callback);
    //
    // }

    private void showPickerFragment(PickerFragment<?> fragment) {
        fragment.setOnErrorListener(new PickerFragment.OnErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onError(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment, FacebookException error) {
                String text = "Exception";
                Toast toast = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                toast.show();
            }
        });

        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container, fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        controlsContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        // We want the fragment fully created so we can use it immediately.
        fm.executePendingTransactions();

        fragment.loadData(false);
    }

    private void onClickPickFriends() {
        final FriendPickerFragment fragment = new FriendPickerFragment();

        setFriendPickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void setFriendPickerListeners(final FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new FriendPickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onFriendPickerDone(fragment);
            }
        });
    }

    private void onFriendPickerDone(FriendPickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        String results = "";

        List<GraphUser> selection = fragment.getSelection();
        tags = selection;
        if (selection != null && selection.size() > 0) {
            ArrayList<String> names = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (GraphUser user : selection) {
                names.add(user.getName());
            }
            results = TextUtils.join(", ", names);
        } else {
            results = "no_friends_selected";
        }

        showAlert("you_picked", results);
    }

    private void onPlacePickerDone(PlacePickerFragment fragment) {
        FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
        fm.popBackStack();

        String result = "";

        GraphPlace selection = fragment.getSelection();
        if (selection != null) {
            result = selection.getName();
        } else {
            result = "no_place_selected";
        }

        place = selection;

        showAlert("you_picked", result);
    }

    private void onClickPickPlace() {
        final PlacePickerFragment fragment = new PlacePickerFragment();
        fragment.setLocation(SEATTLE_LOCATION);
        fragment.setTitleText("pick_seattle_place");

        setPlacePickerListeners(fragment);

        showPickerFragment(fragment);
    }

    private void setPlacePickerListeners(final PlacePickerFragment fragment) {
        fragment.setOnDoneButtonClickedListener(new PlacePickerFragment.OnDoneButtonClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDoneButtonClicked(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                onPlacePickerDone(fragment);
            }
        });
        fragment.setOnSelectionChangedListener(new PlacePickerFragment.OnSelectionChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onSelectionChanged(PickerFragment<?> pickerFragment) {
                if (fragment.getSelection() != null) {
                    onPlacePickerDone(fragment);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void showAlert(String title, String message) {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(this).setTitle(title).setMessage(message).setPositiveButton("ok", null).show();
    }

    private boolean hasPublishPermission() {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        return session != null && session.getPermissions().contains("publish_actions");
    }

    private void performPublish(PendingAction action, boolean allowNoSession) {
        Session session = Session.getActiveSession();
        if (session != null) {
            pendingAction = action;
            if (hasPublishPermission()) {
                handlePendingAction();
                return;
            } else if (session.isOpened()) {
                // We need to get new permissions, then complete the action when
                // we get called back.
                session.requestNewPublishPermissions(new Session.NewPermissionsRequest(this, PERMISSION));
                return;
            }
        }

        if (allowNoSession) {
            pendingAction = action;
            handlePendingAction();
        }
    }
}
```