# Sharing photos on Picasa through Android app

Tags: android, picasa

I am working on an android project, in which the user can share their photos through the Picassa application.

Can anyone please share some tips or pointers as to how I can accomplish the same?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the user has Picasa application already installed

you should try these solutions

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/19218290/3518278
>
> http://www.codeofaninja.com/2013/02/android-share-intent-example.html